# Where can you learn to download and learn tkz-fct?

Tags: tkz-fct

I came across this package called tkz-fct, used for drawing functions and graphs. Are there any articles or papers that show how to download it and learn it? Thank you. (I am using Winedit as my editor)

Comment: You can download it on CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-fct It is part of TeX Live and MiKTeX, though, so if you have one of either installed you should already have it installed on your machine. The documentation is in French (I don't know whether a translation exists).

Comment: For non-French speaking users who want to plot functions in with Ti*k*Z-based methods, there is also the pgfplots  package and the datavisualization library.

Comment: Which types of packages or documents do you need to make it work?

Comment: \usepackage{pgfplots} for pgfplots. In order to address someone specific in a comment, you need to use @marmot, say.

Comment: You can ask here `:)`.

Comment: For `tkz-fct` to work, it is necessary to install `gnuplot` beforehand. On Windows I have indicated the procedure in my question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/456362/138900

Comment: Thanks for posting those comments! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tkz-fct` is part of texlive and miktex so you should have it anyway or can easily install it via `tlmgr` or the miktex equivalent.

It includes an 89 page manual that is full of examples (although the text is in french). In texlive you can view that via `texdoc tkz-fct` or see the pdf on the web at http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tkz-fct/tkz-fct-screen.pdf

Comment: It seems to me that it is also necessary to install gnuplot on the operating system.

Comment: Thanks @AndréC . I guess that's what section 3.1 of the manual says, which has a diagram of the program flow (I haven't actually read the manual:-) ....