# tkz-fct not creating a visible graph (bis)

Tags: gnuplot, tkz-fct

The solution given  in the [same question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211109/138900) asked by @A.Ellett  does not work for me.
I am running Windows 10 and I installed gnuplot `gp525-win64-mingw.exe`  as indicated by the manual after [downloading it here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/5.2.5/):

[image: gnuplot-sourceforge]

During installation, I checked the box `Add application directory to your environmental path` as indicated in the manual.

[image: gnuplot-install]
I added `--enable-write18` as indicated in the manual as well as  `--shell-escape` as indicated in the above mentioned solution.

[image: pdflatex]

Despite this I still don't get the curve as you can see:
[image: courbe]

The error is the following

> Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `test-media.tkzfct.table' not
>   found. on input line 9.

Edit :  Added the log file

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit) (preloaded format=latex 2018.10.23)  23 OCT 2018 12:50
entering extended mode
**./test-media.tex
(test-media.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgf.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common.tex"
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks14
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.te
x")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-latex.def"
\pgfutil@abb=\box26
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ms\everyshi.sty"
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex"
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
Package: pgf 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 99.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\dvips.def"
File: dvips.def 2017/06/20 v3.1d Graphics/color driver for dvips
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen105
\Gin@req@width=\dimen106
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex"
Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks16
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks17

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.te
x"
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks18
))
\pgf@x=\dimen107
\pgf@y=\dimen108
\pgf@xa=\dimen109
\pgf@ya=\dimen110
\pgf@xb=\dimen111
\pgf@yb=\dimen112
\pgf@xc=\dimen113
\pgf@yc=\dimen114
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count88
\c@pgf@countb=\count89
\c@pgf@countc=\count90
\c@pgf@countd=\count91
\t@pgf@toka=\toks19
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks20
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks21
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgf.cfg"
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-dvips.def

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-dvips.def"
File: pgfsys-dvips.def 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.25)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-common-postscr
ipt.def"
File: pgfsys-common-postscript.def 2008/10/01  (rcs-revision 1.22)
\pgf@objectcount=\count92
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.t
ex"
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count93
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count94
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.t
ex"
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty"
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex"
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathutil.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathparser.code.tex"
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen115
\pgfmath@count=\count95
\pgfmath@box=\box27
\pgfmath@toks=\toks22
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks24
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometr
ic.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code
.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarit
hmetics.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex"
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count96
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen117
\pgf@picminy=\dimen118
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen121
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen122
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen123
\pgf@xx=\dimen124
\pgf@xy=\dimen125
\pgf@yx=\dimen126
\pgf@yy=\dimen127
\pgf@zx=\dimen128
\pgf@zy=\dimen129
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.c
ode.tex"
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen130
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen131
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.
tex"
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen132
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen133
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2015/05/08  (rcs-revision 1.46)
\pgfpic=\box28
\pgf@hbox=\box29
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box30
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count97
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen134
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations
.code.tex"
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2015/08/07  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen135
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen136
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen137
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex"
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.te
x"
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.
code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2015/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.43)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen138
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex"
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen139
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count98
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.te
x"
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.t
ex"
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.21)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box31
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.t
ex"
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex"
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2014/03/21  (rcs-revision 1.35)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box32
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.tex"
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2015/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\compatibility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.
sty"
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen140
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen141
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\compatibility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.
sty"
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgffor.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\math\pgfmath.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgffor.code.tex"
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex")
\pgffor@iter=\dimen142
\pgffor@skip=\dimen143
\pgffor@stack=\toks25
\pgffor@toks=\toks26
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\tikz.code.tex"
Package: tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.
code.tex"
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2013/08/31 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count99
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen144
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen145
\tikz@lasty=\dimen146
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen147
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen148
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen149
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen150
\tikz@figbox=\box33
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box34
\tikz@tempbox=\box35
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box36
\tikztreelevel=\count100
\tikznumberofchildren=\count101
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count102
\tikz@fig@count=\count103

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex"
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2013/09/17  (rcs-revision 1.8)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count104
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count105
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count106
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count107

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikz
librarytopaths.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tkz-fct\tkz-fct.sty"
Package: tkz-fct 2011/06/01 1.16 c function 
\tkz@tkzf@fct=\count108

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tkz-base\tkz-base.sty"
Package: tkz-base 2018/09/19 1.16 d tkz-base

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikz
librarycalc.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex 2013/07/15 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikz
libraryarrows.code.tex"
File: tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex 2008/01/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\pgflibraryarrows.code.t
ex"
File: pgflibraryarrows.code.tex 2013/09/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.16)
\arrowsize=\dimen151
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikz
libraryplotmarks.code.tex"
File: tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2008/01/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\pgflibraryplotmarks.cod
e.tex"
File: pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2015/08/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.14)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikz
librarypositioning.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex 2008/10/06 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikz
libraryshapes.misc.code.tex"
File: tikzlibraryshapes.misc.code.tex 2008/01/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\shapes\pgflibraryshapes
.misc.code.tex"
File: pgflibraryshapes.misc.code.tex 2013/07/18 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.5)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikz
librarydecorations.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmoduledecorations.code
.tex"
\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance=\dimen152
\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance=\dimen153
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcompleteddistance=\dimen154
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance=\dimen155
\pgf@decorate@distancetomove=\dimen156
\pgf@decorate@repeatstate=\count109
\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude=\dimen157
\pgfdecorationsegmentlength=\dimen158
)
\tikz@lib@dec@box=\box37
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikz
librarydecorations.markings.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\decorations\pgflibraryd
ecorations.markings.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikz
librarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\decorations\pgflibraryd
ecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikz
librarypatterns.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarypatterns.code.tex 2008/01/15 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.2)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\pgflibrarypatterns.code
.tex"
File: pgflibrarypatterns.code.tex 2008/03/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.13)
)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\numprint\numprint.sty"
Package: numprint 2012/08/20 v1.39 Print numbers (HH)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\array.sty"
Package: array 2018/04/30 v2.4h Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen159
\ar@mcellbox=\box38
\extrarowheight=\dimen160
\NC@list=\toks27
\extratabsurround=\skip43
\backup@length=\skip44
\ar@cellbox=\box39
)
\c@nprt@mantissa@digitsbefore=\count110
\c@nprt@mantissa@digitsafter=\count111
\c@nprt@exponent@digitsbefore=\count112
\c@nprt@exponent@digitsafter=\count113
\nprt@digitwidth=\skip45
\nprt@sepwidth=\skip46
\nprt@decimalwidth=\skip47
\nprt@blockwidth=\skip48
\nprt@digittoks=\toks28
\nprt@pretoks=\toks29
\nprt@posttoks=\toks30
\nprt@thisdigit=\count114
\nprt@curpos=\count115
\nprt@rndpos=\count116
\c@nprt@digitsfirstblock=\count117
\c@nprt@blockcnt=\count118
\c@nprt@cntprint=\count119

No configuration file `numprint.cfg' found.)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp.sty"
Package: fp 1995/04/02

`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\defpattern.sty"
Package: defpattern 1994/10/12
\actioncount=\count120
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-basic.sty"
Package: fp-basic 1996/05/13
\FP@xs=\count121
\FP@xia=\count122
\FP@xib=\count123
\FP@xfa=\count124
\FP@xfb=\count125
\FP@rega=\count126
\FP@regb=\count127
\FP@regs=\count128
\FP@times=\count129
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-addons.sty"
Package: fp-addons 1995/03/15
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-snap.sty"
Package: fp-snap 1995/04/05
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-exp.sty"
Package: fp-exp 1995/04/03
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-trigo.sty"
Package: fp-trigo 1995/04/14
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-pas.sty"
Package: fp-pas 1994/08/29
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-random.sty"
Package: fp-random 1995/02/23
\FPseed=\count130
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-eqn.sty"
Package: fp-eqn 1995/04/03
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-upn.sty"
Package: fp-upn 1996/10/21
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-eval.sty"
Package: fp-eval 1995/04/03
))
\tkzRadius=\dimen161
\tkzLength=\dimen162
\tkz@radi=\dimen163
\tkz@ax=\dimen164
\tkz@ay=\dimen165
\tkz@bx=\dimen166
\tkz@by=\dimen167
\tkz@cx=\dimen168
\tkz@cy=\dimen169
\tkz@dx=\dimen170
\tkz@dy=\dimen171

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tkz-base\tkz-tools-utilities.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tkz-base\tkz-tools-arith.tex"
File: tkz-tool-arith.tex tkz-tool-arith 1.161 d
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tkz-base\tkz-tools-base.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tkz-base\tkz-tools-misc.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tkz-base\tkz-tools-math.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tkz-base\tkz-obj-points.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tkz-base\tkz-obj-segments.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tkz-base\tkz-obj-marks.tex"
\tkz@cntmk=\count131
)))
(test-media.aux)
\openout1 = `test-media.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
 ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 10.
\openout3 = `test-media.tkzfct.gnuplot'.

runsystem(gnuplot test-media.tkzfct.gnuplot)...executed.



Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `test-media.tkzfct.table' not found. on inp
ut line 10.

[1

] (test-media.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 14108 strings out of 492967
 297816 string characters out of 3135749
 363344 words of memory out of 3000000
 17711 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 55i,5n,83p,414b,756s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on test-media.dvi (1 page, 14996 bytes).
```

As advised by TorbjørnT. I ask a new question. What's going on?

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: you may need to reboot for that environment change to take effect (it depends on how your local things are set up)

Comment: `runsystem(gnuplot test-media.tkzfct.gnuplot)...executed.` so it is all good on the tex side but gnuplot failed to make the required plot, what happens if you open  a cmd window and type `gnuplot` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Great, it was just that, after restarting, everything works fine. You can modify your answer so that I can validate it.

Comment: done:-)..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code posted in the linked answer works in texlive 2018

[image]

You get the warning

```
Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `bb007.tkzfct.table' not found. on input li
ne 9.
```

if you do not use `--shell-escape` (or presumably if gnuplot can not be found in the path)

Look for gnuplot in the log file, if the problem is `--shell-escape` then the log will show

```
runsystem(gnuplot bb007.tkzfct.gnuplot)...disabled (restricted).
```

If `--shell-escape` is enabled then the log will look like

```
runsystem(gnuplot bb007.tkzfct.gnuplot)...executed.

Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `bb007.tkzfct.table' not found. on input li
ne 9.
```

which means that TeX tried to run gnuplot but it failed to make the plot table data for some reason.

Note that gnuplot needs to be **in the path** (which may **require a system reboot** if you have only just installed it).

Comment: @AndréC I was adding more data, check your log file for gnuplot messages (see above, which I was writing as you made this comment)

Comment: I just added the log file to the question:)