# Installing GNUplot

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to run this program but my output is only the axes themselves! I thought my MiKTeX console updates all softwares for my TeXnicCenter platform but apparently not since when I run this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% use GNUplot (avaiable in TeXLive)
\draw[->] (-4.5,0) -- (4.5,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-4.5) -- (0,4.5) node[left] {$y$};

\draw[blue,thick] plot[raw gnuplot,smooth] function {
f(x,y) = x*y*y+2*(x**3)*(y**3)-y-1;
set xrange [-4:4];
set yrange [-4:4];
set view 0,0;
set isosample 500,500;
set cont base;
set cntrparam levels incre 0,0.1,0;
unset surface;
splot f(x,y);
 };
 \node[below=5mm,blue] at (current bounding box.south) 
  {The curve $xy^2+2x^3y^3=y+1$.};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

My Output is without plot:

[image]

Please advise my about GNUplot. This is a little confusing. I only found the following download page: https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/
I get confused with so many files!

Comment: Although `tikz` provides `gnuplot` facilities or uses `gnuplot`, the installation of gnuplot is not really on-topic on `TeX.SE`. There is nothing difficult on selecting `https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/5.2.6/gp526-win64-mingw_2.exe/download` and download and run the self-extracting document.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer I see that tikz provides. I did the instruction above but no result in the pdf output. But I was able to run the code on their windows platform but not out put in a pdf in the article documentclass

Comment: Can you run `gnuplot` from the command line?

Comment: Yes I just can not run in my TeXNicCenter editor and output as pdf

Comment: You have to run `pdflatex` with the option `shell-escape` otherwise it is not allowed to run an external program from within a pdflatex run

Comment: @Herbert, are you saying I need to add the package gnuplot-lua-tikz to my program files and run pdflatex so it gets picked-up by the editor?

Comment: No, in your editor you have to define how `pdflatex` or whatelse is run. For example for TeXstudio I have defined `lualatex --shell-escape  -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` Every Editor has it's own way to define such commands.

Comment: For Latex>PDF  in TeXnicCenter it is  `-shell-escape -synctex=-1 -interaction=nonstopmode "%wm"` It is **best** to **copy** Latex>PDF and edit a new profile via the `Build` options when adding -shell- escape simply call the profile a name like "with gnuplot"

Comment: Are you saying I have to  redefine my output profile with that command line? Currently it reads -max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode "%wm"

Comment: I tried but it says cannot execute command ! I created a separate profile so I don't mess up my current settings

Comment: possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/456362/138900

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tkz-fct not creating a visible graph (bis)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456362/tkz-fct-not-creating-a-visible-graph-bis)

Comment: Try my stress test MWE for gnuplot at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/456328/170109

Comment: @AnderC I finally got it to work by accident. AnderC's comment helped plus I needed to compile first with KJO's suggestion then recompile again normally to output the pdf. . This is  tough for me to understand as I am a rookie here